# How to do regex filter in restful service

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot

I need to write web-service on spring-boot, just using for example:

`/hello/contacts?nameFilter=^.*[abc].*$` 
and return all names from DB w/o symbols a,b,c (just like reverse) and etc.

In controller class I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
)
List<Contact> getAllContactsByName(@RequestParam(name = "nameFilter") String nameFilter);
```

service class:

```
@Autowired
private ContactDao contactDao;

@Override
public List<Contact> getContactsByNameFilter(String nameFilter) {
    return nameFilter == "" ? findAllContacts() : contactDao.findByRegex(nameFilter);
}


public List<Contact> findAllContacts(){
    return contactDao.findAll();
}
```

How I should implement method `findByRegex(nameFilter)` in dao layer class?
Do I must do reverse filter in service class, not in dao. And how I can do it without using sql.

Sorry for some mistakes and my english, just started to learn spring-boot, after java se courses.

Comment: I would highly suggest not allowing a user to pass a regex to your backend.  Instead I would create a map of associate keys to the regex patterns.  Then all the user has to (and can) provide is the associated key.  They have no ability to alter the regex and it maintains fully in your control.

Comment: `namefilter == ""` is bad... use `nameFilter.isEmpty()` or `"".equals(nameFilter)`

Comment: @lance-java or check the length, ^_^

Comment: Yes i understand this, but my task is just pass regex to filtering query to DB and get response. 
w/o frontend, just write in url [localhost] (http://localhost:8080/hello/contacts?nameFilter=^J.*$)
and get all contacts which do not start with letter J

Answer (score 0):

> And how I can do it without using sql.

The only way to do it completely w/o SQL is to fetch all contacts into memory, and test each of them against given RegEx, ignoring those that match. For example (using Java 8 features)

```
public List<Contact> findByRegex(String nameFilter) {
    return contactDao.findAll().stream()
                .filter(c -> !c.getName().matches(nameFilter))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or did you mean

> And how I can do it without using **PLAIN** sql.

?

Then you may try JPQL/HQL/CriteriaAPI

Comment: thank you
and one++ question more, if in DB 1M+ contacts, how should i fetch all contacts into memory? should i use something like cache if i want to use filter few times?

Comment: In that case you must use combination of loops and paging -- `SELECT .... LIMIT X ... OFFSET Y` (native SQL) until all records are processed. Or similar approaches in HQL (see `Pageable` class).

However it is quite weird restriction - not to use SQL while having 1M records in table. It is a good practice to delegate sorting and filtering (if not too complicated) to the DBMS, instead of doing that in memory